# eliminate the last commit, but I have some changes done too

Tags: git

I am having a bit of a difficult situation with git.

**The situation**

I had a branch called *myFeature* and for some reason (when I was rebasing some other branch) I got some changes in my code. Just in case I added and committed it.

So now I got the following history

```
11111 (myFeature) Unidentified changes
22222  the last change I did
33333  the previous one before that
```

Anyway, I realized that my program does not work with the last changes but I was in a hurry so I did

```
git checkout 22222
```

With that my program compiled but I needed some configuration change so I changed a file *my_configuration.yaml*. With that my program worked well.

Now I want to preserve my changes so I have to:

- Eliminate the last commit 11111
- Preserve the configuration file

Right now when I do `git log --all` I got

```
11111 (myFeature) Unidentified changes
22222  (HEAD) the last change I did
33333  the previous one before that
```

and `git status` gives

```
HEAD detached at 22222
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   my_configuration.yaml
```

I was thinking of a git Reset (not sure soft or hard) and that would be fine but the thing is I don't want to lose my configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you said

```
git checkout 22222
```

...you put yourself in detached head mode. Git warned you when you did that, but you didn't listen. In detached head mode you are not on any branch and you cannot preserve your work.

The status message tells you what to do. Add and commit! Only commits are saved.

But you are still not on a branch so your commit will be lost. So: Write down the id of the new commit. Now checkout myFeature, and *cherry-pick* that new commit by its id.

If you are serious that you also want to "Eliminate the last commit 11111", then *revert* that commit by *its* id. You can do that before or after the cherry pick.

So you did this:

```
git checkout 2222
# edit to get good state
```

So now:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'good config'
```

(write down the id of the new commit, let's say 4444)

```
git checkout myFeature 
git revert 1111
git cherry-pick 4444
```

Comment: So I should commit from a detach branch? and then cherry pick in the myfeature branch? But how do I revert the last commit first?

Comment: Note : "commit from a detach branch?" There is no such thing as a detach branch. You are on a branch _or_ you are detached. You cannot be both.